# TypeScript: Create union type dynamicaly from interface

Tags: typescript

I want to generate a type `Response`

```js
type Response = 
{
    code: 200
    body: {
        msg: string
    }
} | {
    code: 400
    body: {
        errorCode: number
    }
}
```

from `Foo` (simplified version of the type generated [by](https://github.com/drwpow/openapi-typescript).

```js
interface Foo {
    200: {
        msg: string
    }
    400: {
        errorCode: number
    }
}
```

I tried below but it doesn't work.

```js
type Response = {
    code: keyof Foo // 200 | 400
    body: Foo[keyof Foo] // {msg: string} | {errorCode: number}
}


const res: Response = {
    code: 200,
    body: {
        errorCode: 1 // not get an error
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are mixing all possible `code` types with all possible `body` types.  You need to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) instead to explicitly iterate over *each* key `K` of `Foo` and make each element a function of `K` the key, and `Foo[K]` the value.  This produces a new object type like `{200: {code: 200, ...}, 400: {code: 400, ...}` which you want to [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to get the union of its properties:

```
type Resp = { [K in keyof Foo]: { code: K, body: Foo[K] } }[keyof Foo];

/* type Resp = {
    code: 200;
    body: {
        msg: string;
    };
} | {
    code: 400;
    body: {
        errorCode: number;
    };
} */
```

(I renamed it `Resp` because there's already a `Response` in global scope I don't want to collide with).

Then you get the desired error when using the wrong `body` with a given `code`:

```
const res: Resp = {
    code: 200,
    body: {
        errorCode: 1 // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Type '{ errorCode: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ msg: string; }'.
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBMADMQFw74HIC2AzgOYV1hSgNUC+VALKRXmrJoUdFADC6ACYQKIAK40ARtC65uuMAE8ADigBKEOjuQBeHMgDaAaWShkAawhb0MNJgC6A5Ammzk1gA0yErSWhQY6DYeyJyxlk4ubpEeANy4uAD0AFTI2nrIhsZmlEK+MhQkxOlCoVLhpULU9EzILGwgDDXUnOlxAD6NBOX+fNVUBHUNgk0EImKSFcgKytDdBL3qyNmZGbi+ICzIUEYURSbmM8N+laSBEyFhAg9C8xI3yACMyJmZwlCiKAAQgevwIAD9IVDoZDQX8ACq6FAAcmw-0Bi38KxUUFSsWRdjoy3QYGQcDodGADBAcCUABsUGAsPkUWiWsxWOw8ZxkQA6B7cThAA)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I've been looking for!